# Browser Caching in ASP.NET Core 1.1 not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

So I followed the guide [here](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/response-caching-in-asp-net-core-1-1/) (excluding some of the application specific items like Application Insights).

Startup.cs was modified in these two areas:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
  {
    options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
    options.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(new[] { "image/svg+xml" });
  }); 

  // Add framework services.
  services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
      options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection")));

  services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection")));


  services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
      .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
      .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
  services.AddResponseCaching();
  services.AddMvc();

  // Add application services.
  services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
  services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
  app.UseResponseCompression();
  app.UseResponseCaching();
  loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
  loggerFactory.AddDebug();

  if (env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    app.UseBrowserLink();
  }
  else
  {
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
  }

  app.UseStaticFiles();

  app.UseIdentity();

  // Add external authentication middleware below. To configure them please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715

  app.UseMvc(routes =>
  {
    routes.MapRoute(
              name: "default",
              template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
  });
}
```

And on various Controllers for pages, I call ResponseCache like this (set it to 2 minutes, not sure if this is what people traditionallly set it to):

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 120)]
public IActionResult Index()
{
  return View();
}
```

After deploying to Azure, I can repeatedly hit F5 and still see 200 in network traffic. The goal is to cache CSS, JS, and pages (well, pages that aren't part of [Authorize] managed controllers).

update (of sorts): the unfortunate thing is that I have reviewed quite a few guides on this and it seems they all inherently say the same things (main difference is not relying on the Response Caching Nuget package and going with a hard coded version, same non-results though), but for some reason this doesn't work. In a Web Forms application (2.0 upgraded to 4.0), I was able to achieve this with minimal effort.

Answer (score 0):

When you hit F5, you will always get a new response, bypassing the cache. If instead you try to navigate to a link (...), you will see that the response is indeed cached.

Comment: Typically when I hit just F5, I get 304s in there as well for other sites I've done. This one it is all 200s. Now, I could do a hard one where it'll bypass caching but that isn't the case here. The primary symptom that made me take notice of this was PageSpeed Insights flagging images/css/etc. as no caching headers

Comment: To test, add an A element to a page (or action) that is being cached, and try to navigate to it. You will notice that the action isn't hit.

Comment: From index, I clicked on a link within the page with Network tab of dev tools open. All of the assets came back 200. Even the images that are part of the layout and the CSS that makes up the theme (also served from the layout).